# How do I manage session in Android login/logout?

Tags: php, android, session

I am creating an application in which user logins and logout, the data comes from mysql server using php web services, now i want to maintain session when user login and destroy it when user logouts , i'm using

```
intent.putExtra("SESSION_ID", sessionId);
```

how to reset it on logout
does this will work as session or i had to do something else

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preference for set or reset session

For save session to shared preference for login

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("session", sessionId);editor.apply();
```

For reset session to shared preference on logout

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("session", "0");editor.apply();
```

For retrieve data from preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String sessionData= prefs.getString("session", null); //SessionId that you saved in preference
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` to manage your `session`.

**Here is an example:**

**1.** Create a class named `SessionManager` like below:

```
public class SessionManager {

    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

    Context context;

    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "TEST";

    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN = "IS_LOGGED_IN";


    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, isLoggedIn);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();

        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
    }
}
```

**2.** Update `session` status using `setLogin()` method.

**LOGIN:**

```
SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
sessionManager.setLogin(true);
```

**LOGOUT:**

```
SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
sessionManager.setLogin(false);
```

Here is an good Tutorial about [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Using sharedPreferences you can do it much easier. Make a sharedPreference variable and clear it when you log out.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreference("filename", 0);
SharedPreferences. Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("varName",value);
```

Later when session log out

```
editor.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Set/login

```
SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences("Your PREF_NAME",Private_Mode);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
editor.putString("SESSION_ID", sessionId);
editor.commit();
```

For logout

```
SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences("Your PREF_NAME",Private_Mode);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
pref.edit().remove(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID);
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```